# How to avoid regulatory approval regulations, when chosing a RF module?

Tags: rf, radio, xbee, zigbee, standard

I've been trying to implement RF capabilities into my projecto, but I don't want to pay thousands of euros to get an ETSI certification in case it gets into production.
I know that if I get a complete module like Xbee I could avoid that problem, but those modules are a little bit too big for what I want to make.
How to avoid ETSI regulations (like some kind of frequency or dB range that doesn't need aproval, or a little smaller zigbee modules or at least some kind of list that displays modules by standard compliance)?

Comment: What sort of RF capabilities?

Comment: See atmel based zigbits(http://eewiki.net/display/Wireless/Atmel+Zigbit+-+802.15.4+-+ZigBee+Module) same way freescale, microchip,Ti, Silicon labs have good standard modules....

Comment: Low range (30 to 100m), low data rate (about 250kbps or even less) and low power.

Comment: Many modules come pre-certified.  I am not familiar with ETSI.  I know you can get pre-certified for FCC and CE.

Comment: I too would like to know how pre-certification and module certification works in this case.

Comment: I think even "ready-certified" stuff does not get you round the problem if you build them into something & start selling it, I believe you will probably still have to get the entire product certified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how it works in Europe, but in the US, if you are buying just the module, then even though it has an FCC ID on it, you still need to get it tested in combination with your own antenna.

*However*, if you buy a module and antenna mounted together, such as this ZigBee (notice it has a prominent CE mark):

[image]

then you don't have to do any additional RF testing that I know of. The datasheet for this particular module says it is certified for ETSI EN 300 328 and EN 300 440 (Europe), FCC CFR47 Part 15 (US), and ARIB STDT66 (Japan).

Note the PCB is only a little larger than the module and antenna together; the small space between the module and antenna is no doubt dictated by ground plane rules for the antenna.

The exception to the above is if you have more than one radio in your product, e.g. both Bluetooth and a cell module, then you have to have the combination tested together.

Answer (score 4):

Pre-certification may apply to the module you are using, but you are still required for CE marking of the device.

Part of the process for CE marking requires you to show evidence that your DEVICE conforms to the relevant harmonized requirements that covers emission and susceptibility.

So you are still required to obtain CE marking to sell your product on the European market place, but you may be able to limit the number of tests you perform and not cover the intended radiator of your pre-certified module.  You will save some testing effort, but not all.